# Tool to Document Database

Tags: database, erd

Is there a tool (preferably open source) that can be used to produce documentation (preferably html) for a database?  I'd like a tool that can show the tables and relationships visually and allow you to enter a description for each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Red Gate SQL Doc to create HTML/PDF/Doc based documentation for the database. The Good thing is that you can use this within SQL Server Management Studio.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/